# How to ignore specific query parameter with varnish cache?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

`/swatches/ajax/media/?product_id=17620&isAjax=true&_=1524469655019`

I need to cache this request with varnish, but i need to ignore the last query parameter `_=1524469655019`.

I am not sure how varnish internally works, but i suppose it makes the cache uid key from the url requested. So in my case it would need it only to create the uid key from this url

`/swatches/ajax/media/?product_id=17620&isAjax=true`

Doing something like `req.url ~ "^/swatches/(.*)$"` would not work as varnish would still use the entire url for cache uid.

Comment: You can use this module https://github.com/NYTimes/libvmod-queryfilter

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/112531/ignoring-get-parameters-in-varnish-vcl

Comment: You can achieve this easily by nuster cache server, https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just strip the `_=` from the QS.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?_=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?_=AAA"
  set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?_=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?_=AAA&foo=bar"

}
```

keep in mind this will strip the QS - and the QS is not forwarded to the backend.
if you need it in the backend you'd need to do in in `vcl_hash`

> beware if you have a custom vcl_hash, to include the default rules, as the custom removes the default hash parameters.
> `http.host || client.ip`
>
> VCL hash is the part the generates the cache-uuid

```
sub vcl_hash {
  set req.http.hash_url = regsuball(req.url,"\?_=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?_=AAA"
  set req.http.hash_url = regsuball(req.http.hash_url,"\?_=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?_=AAA&foo=bar"
  hash_data(req.http.hash_url);
  if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
  } else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
  }
}
```

this way, the request that produces a `MISS` also passes `_=`  to the backend.
and there is no explicit need for a vmod in such a simple case.